# Find all instances of CacheKey from CacheClient object and remove one or more from it

Tags: servicestack

I am caching couple of requests with following unique keys... I am using In-Memory cache.

```
urn:Product:/site.api.rest/product?pagenumber=0&pagesize=0&params=<Product><ProductID>3</ProductID></Product>
urn:Product:/site.api.rest/product?pagenumber=0&pagesize=0&params=<Product><ProductID>1</ProductID></Product>
urn:Product:/site.api.rest/product?pagenumber=0&pagesize=0&params=<Product><ProductID>5</ProductID></Product>
urn:Product:/site.api.rest/product?pagenumber=0&pagesize=0&params=<Product><ProductID>3</ProductID><Description>test</Description></Product>
...
...
```

Now, in create/update/delete I would like to remove specific cache (based upon what params passed in the request body, for example everything with 3.

In order to do that I would get singleNode from request params (for example: 3).

How can I?

```
Get all cache objects which matches <ProductID>3</ProductID> and remove it?
Also, what is the right approach to remove cache?
    base.RequestContext.RemoveFromCache(base.Cache, cachekey);
    or
    CacheClient.Remove(keyname)?
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better approach, which is to use generational caching.

When you construct your cache key include a generation number e.g.

> urn:Product:**gen_1**:/site.api.rest/product?pagenumber=0&pagesize=0&params=

(This number could be stored as a counter in your caching service.)

Then when you want to (pseudo) invalidate a large set of cached items, just increment the generation number.

Just be sure to set an expiry date on the cached items so that older generations are cleaned up over time.

Comment: That could work if I want to invalidate all old caches, in that case I would use **FlushAll()**. But I want to find list of caches which matches my partial filter **<ProductID>3</ProductID>** (which I derive from request object in case of put/post/delete) from Cache object and pass it to `RemoveAll(IEnumerable<string> keys);` It would be helpful it there is a function **GetAll()** without any parameters which would return all cache objects. _Thank you._

Comment: I think you missed the point a little. In your example when you construct a cache key for ProductId 3, you would include the 3 in the cache key along with the generation key.

Comment: I found a extension method under **ServiceStack.CacheAccess.Providers.CacheClientExtensions** which does the job. `public static void RemoveByPattern(this ICacheClient cacheClient, string pattern)`. Thanks for all your help.